# On the concept of non-denegerate bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

A trivial concept clarification: Is it possible to have a non-degenerate bilinear form $\langle, \rangle: V \times V \to F$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a finite field $F$ such that $\langle y, x \rangle = 0$ for all $y \in V$ does not imply that $x = 0$?

Comment: Please tell us how you are *defining* a non-degenerate bilinear form.

Comment: @KCd: It's a map $\langle , \rangle$ such that $v \to (x \mapsto \langle x, v \rangle)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: there are no such examples over any field (finite or infinite).  Did something you read suggest there are some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG, $V = F^n$. Write $\langle y, x \rangle = (y, Bx)$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the dot product, and $B_{ij} = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$. Nondegenerate means $B$ is invertible. If $\langle y, x \rangle = (y, Bx)$ for all $y \in V$, then taking $y = e_i$, $i = 1, \dots, n$ yields $Bx = 0$, and therefore $x = 0$.

Comment: Can I find a proof on the equivalence of the definition of non-degeneracy via isomorphism and the one  you give via non-singular matrix representation?

Comment: @KKslider  see Theorem 3.1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @KKslider It's easy from the definition. For $\Phi$ defined by $\Phi(x) = (y \mapsto \langle y, x \rangle)$, $\ker(\Phi) = \ker(B)$.